# Calling PowerShell Script from Server Side Actionscript Or Something Else

Tags: javascript, actionscript, powershell, ssas

I have a question that has stumped me for weeks.

Basically, one way or another, I need to call a powershell script that runs avconv / ffmpeg from either 1) server-side actionscript, or 2) when a web page loads such as Javascript.

The first one is ideal since I can listen for an event and trigger the command line to call the powershell, but I don't know if that is possible and from my research it seems either a) you cannot or b) there's not a lot of information about SSAS.

Keep in mind the SSAS I'm talking about is Flash media server's Server-Side Actionscript (JS 1.5)

The second one seems like it could work but I forsee permission issues and what not - but if it is possible I'm very interested to know.

Another idea is NodeJS or something else, Python, I don't know, but I need a way to trigger the script on the server-side after a certain event.  I cannot really listen for events in powershell in this context, as I need to call this when a stream is published to the fms application

My last ditch effort is to have the SSAS update an xml tree with the stream information when one is published to it and have powershell read it every so often and fire off when the xml is populated with stream information.

Any help or pointers in a direction would be very much appreciated!

Thank you all

M

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like something that should be done handled by a scripting language on your server, like php, python, ruby, etc. It should be client via javascript and Ajax, or via client side Actionscript, since it sounds like it depends on some activity on the client side. Most scripting languages on the server will have access to command line, and be able to execute other programs.

For example, in php, you could call a script like do-ffmpeg.php that will have the call to exec() http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php. exec could run any kind of commands on your server. So, I'd stick with your answer #2.